# How to save data from a planner in real time database using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, calendar

I have a daily planner and a monthly calendar and I want to sincronize them. Every time when a user would tap on a day from the calendar, the planner for that day would open and should show the events that the user created. My problem is that I don't know how to save and receive this data( the events that are planned at a certain hour in the day) from firebase.

Comment: provide some source code...

Comment: Code with what? The planners have some code but it's complex and i should post almost all of it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to figure out the data model you want, this can be done multiple ways but ultimately comes down to future planning on your part. Beyond that, you need to follow the basic guides to getting started with Firebase.

- Initialize your Firebase client
- Login or Authorise your user
- Read and Set data as per your design

example write:

```js
  firebase.database().ref('users/' + userId).set({
    username: name,
    email: email,
    profile_picture : imageUrl
  });
```

and to read data once

```
const dbRef = firebase.database().ref();
dbRef.child("users").child(userId).get().then((snapshot) => {
  if (snapshot.exists()) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
  } else {
    console.log("No data available");
  }
}).catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
});
```

You should get familiar with the realtime documentation [**HERE**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once). The key differences between reading `once` and get updates with `on` and the difference between `set` and `update` allow overwriting data vs merging data.